# Google form to answer sheet to separate sheet to email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to work out a solution to something and whilst I can get snippets of help from the weeb I cannot pin it down to what I want it to do. So, what I want to achieve:

1. A google form is submitted which creates a record in a google spreadsheet.
2. using the query function I take that information instantly to another sheet in the same spreadsheet. Whilst in there it goes through some if statements which creates a unique ID for the submission, separates the date and the time of the submission into separate columns and adds a email  address that needs to be notified of this submission. For the purpose of this test, the submitter and the notification emails are the same.
3. the script monitors the second sheet and, on form submission (trigger), takes the information from the last row in a certain sequence to create an email:

   > ```
   > function formsubmission(e){
   >       var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   >       var sheet = ss.getSheetbyName('email');
   >       var startRow = 2;
   >       var lastRow = e.sheet.getLastRow();
   >       var formid = e.sheet.column[1];
   >       var notificationemail = e.sheet.column[2];  
   >       var formdate = e.sheet.column[3];  
   >       var formtime = e.sheet.column[4];  
   >       var submitter = e.sheet.column[6];
   >       var yn = e.sheet.column[7]; 
   >       var subject = formid + "submitted";
   >       var message = "Thank for answering" + yn + "on" + formdate + "at"+ formtime;
   >       MailApp.sendEmail (notificationgroup, subject, message,{
   >         cc: submitter, 
   >       });
   >     }
   > ```

Needless to say that the above script does not work.

If any of you kind people want to help. The form is test form to which the above refers is [here](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSegEPcwX21nB-TKmZWfpUglmcS_1uGShrC_1hc_fb0LhYbK0g/viewform?usp=sf_link) and the related spreadsheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TmQ_0KIZKyihuiXIXu_7352XF9bMNILzsXQzo3XzTNg/edit?usp=sharing).

I would prefer not to have a separate sheet but the one accepting submissions does not allow for any  functions or anything else in it.

Any help to make the above script work would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Review the form submission [`event object`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) and the methods available for the [`Range` class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range). Note that relying on a combination of the input item responses and the last row in the sheet is not advised, as your calculation sheet has no guarantee to complete its calculations before the script responds to the submission trigger.

Comment: There is no e.sheet